# Masm ассемблер для 7 винды 64 бит

Tags: ассемблер, x86-64, masm

Есть ли такой и где его скачать? (Именно масм, а не другие.) Я решил изучать ассемблер и в книгах в основном авторы пишут на масм ассемблере, а я для своей системы нашел только фасм ассемблер, если масм код вставить в фасм, то будет ошибка, вот и ищу масм ассеблер для 7 винды 64 битной. (Асмы, фасмы, запутался уже.)

Answer (score 2):

есть и 32-битный , и 64-битный. Видел недавно в магазине книжку про 64-битный MASM.

Кажется, они ОБА входят в Visual Studio 2008 и 2010.

MASM 32 можно скачать [здесь](http://www.masm32.com/masmdl.htm)